# How can I categorize my data based on histogram buckets in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a histogram graph generated from `obsoleteness` column inside `my.data`

```r
his.obsoleteness <- (ggplot(my.data, aes(x=obsoleteness)) 
  + geom_histogram(bins = 15,fill = "white", color="Red" )
  + stat_bin(aes(y=..count.., label=..count..), geom="text",bins = 15))
```

I want to add a new column to `my.data` that represents the "bucket number". For example, if a row in the first (smallest bucket) the column should have the value 1, if it's in the second bucket the value should be 2, so on and so forth. Is there an easy way of doing this other than manually assigning the value for every bucket interval?

[image: geom_histogram]

Comment: Can you post your data?

Comment: How should I post it? It's just a single column of numeric values?

Comment: Try using `dput(yourdata)` or creating a subset of `n` values using `dput(head(your data, n)`- also, do you mean `bin` instead of "bucket"?

Comment: I think you’re looking for ?cut

Answer (score 0):

Since bins group data by equal width, you could try:

```
# sample data
my.data <- data.frame(obsoleteness = sample(1:10000, 1000, replace = T))

bins <- 15

my.data$bin <- findInterval(my.data$obsoleteness,
                            quantile(my.data$obsoleteness, 
                                     probs = seq(0, 1, by = 1/bins)))

# > head(my.data,10)
#   obsoleteness bin
#1          4101   7
#2          1702   3
#3          6354  10
#4          7710  12
#5          3575   6
#6          2686   5
#7          6598  10
#8          6983  11
#9          9414  15
#10         9431  15
```